# Electric field off axis inside a charged ring.

Tags: physics, gaussian-integral

If I have a charged ring of radius $a$ what I'm trying to find the electric field of a point $r$ from the axis in the plane for $r\ll a$. The example sheet hints to use a gaussian surfaces of radius $r$ but I'm not sure what purpose a gaussian surface that encloses no charge serves and so i've tried to to is directly.

By symmetry the only component of the field will be radial. Using Coulomb's law in conjunction with the cosine rule I get 
$$E=\frac {\sigma} {4\pi \epsilon_0} \int_{0}^{2\pi} {\frac {r-a\cos(\theta)}{((a^2+r^2)-2ar \cos(\theta))^{3/2}} \ d\theta}$$

Is this integral possible using first year university maths?
Is there an easier way to find the electric field off axis for $r\ll a$ in the plane of a charged ring?

Comment: http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/phys208/exercises/kevan/efield1.html

Comment: that's on the axis which is a much simpler problem.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate in the physics community. Nonetheless, here's a suggestion. If you don't want to use a Gaussian surface and want to tackle that integral directly then expand the integrand in powers of $r/a$ and keep only the leading term since all that you're interested in is the behaviour when $r \ll a$.

Comment: @wltrup It's not that I don't want to use the gaussian surface its more that I don't know how it's of use. Surely the flux out of a  volume with no field is zero? Perhaps this is more relevant to physics but I generally find the maths community to be a lot more helpful and forgiving of my relative inexperience!

Comment: Perhaps you're misinterpreting the hint. Have you thought of a Gaussian wedge of inner radius $r$, outer radius $a + \delta$, spanning an angle $d\theta$ around $\theta$, with the top face just above the plane of the ring and the bottom face just below it?

Comment: Also, if you do consider a Gaussian pillbox of radius $r$ centred at the origin then, while it's true that there's no charge inside, it's still useful since you can then relate the flux through the top and bottom surfaces with the flux through the side. In the limit $r \ll a$, you might be able to find the leading term of the radial component of the electric field on the plane of the ring near the origin.

Comment: I think this must be what the question is hinting at.

Comment: @wltrup can you show how that gaussian wedge looks like ? I am not able to visualize as I have never encountered a gaussian wedge with inner and outer radii. can you attach an image

Comment: Can this be done in a similar manner for magnetic field a bit off-axis inside a rotating ring about its centre ? Using gauss and amperes law ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if we take a very small gaussian pillbox centred on the origin of height $2z$ and radius $r$ in the limit the field out of the top and bottom surfaces is: $$\frac {Qz\pi r^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0(a^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$
therefore as the total charge enclosed is zero and we know the field through the sides of our pillbox is radial and of constant magnitude we can arrive at: $$ \frac {2Qz\pi r^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0(a^2+z^2)^{3/2}} - 4\pi rzE = 0$$ This rearranges to: $$E=\frac{Qr}{8\pi\epsilon_0(a^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$ which is: $$\frac{Qr}{8\pi\epsilon_0a^3}$$ if we take the taylor series and say the $\frac{z^2}{a^2}$  and above terms are negligible in the limit $z<<a$. Seems to be quite wishy washy but it does get the right answer.

Thanks to wltrup for help!

Comment: Can this be done in a similar manner for magnetic field a bit off-axis inside a rotating ring about its centre ? Using gauss and amperes law ?